# Opencv getGaborKernel parameters for filter bank

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, filtering

How opencv getGaborKernel function parameters related to orientation and scale parameters?

I assume theta is orientation, but what refers to scale?

> //! returns the Gabor kernel with the specified parameters
>   CV_EXPORTS_W Mat getGaborKernel( Size ksize, double sigma, double
>   theta, double lambd,double gamma, double psi=CV_PI*0.5, int
>   ktype=CV_64F );

Here is example 5 scales and 8 orientations:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also I found this parameter explanation:
http://matlabserver.cs.rug.nl/edgedetectionweb/web/edgedetection_params.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the meaning of parameters:

- `ksize` Size of the filter returned.
- `sigma` Standard deviation of the gaussian envelope.
- `theta` Orientation of the normal to the parallel stripes of a Gabor function.
- `lambda` Wavelength of the sinusoidal factor.
- `gamma` Spatial aspect ratio.
- `psi` Phase offset.
- `ktype` Type of filter coefficients. It can be `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`.

The orientation can be modified by `theta` and the scale by i.e. `lambda`. Here you have a good tutorial about *[What do the Gabor filter parameters mean?](http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/doku.php?id=public:gabor_filter)*. **Update September 2020**: The link to *What do the Gabor filter parameters mean?* no longer works. Try [*Through The Eyes of Gabor Filter*](https://medium.com/@anuj_shah/through-the-eyes-of-gabor-filter-17d1fdb3ac97) instead.

I also attach the image from the site above:

[image: I have also attach the image from the site]

Copyright by [Juergen Muller](http://www.juergenwiki.de)

Comment: Great, answer. Also here is some code to visualize kernel with sliders https://gist.github.com/YusukeSuzuki/9910030

Comment: How can i specifying wavelength?

Comment: lamdba is definitly the wavelength