# Filter bank taking too long for kernels to be created

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter-bank

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52106477/159072).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bitmap image = DataConverter2d.ReadGray(StandardImage.LenaGray);
        Array2d<double> dImage = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(image);            

        int newWidth = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(dImage.Width) * 2;
        int newHeight = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(dImage.Height) * 2;

        double n = 6;
        double f0 = 0.5;
        double theta = 60;
        double a = 0.4;

        Array2d<Complex> kernel2d = CustomFft(newWidth, newHeight, n, f0, theta, a);

        dImage.PadTo(newWidth, newHeight);
        Array2d<Complex> cImage = DataConverter2d.ToComplex(dImage);
        Array2d<Complex> fImage = FourierTransform.ForwardFft(cImage);

        // FFT convolution .................................................
        Array2d<Complex> fOutput = new Array2d<Complex>(newWidth, newHeight);
        for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++)
            {
                fOutput[x, y] = fImage[x, y] * kernel2d[x, y];
            }
        }

        Array2d<Complex> cOutput = FourierTransform.InverseFft(fOutput);
        Array2d<double> dOutput = Rescale2d.Rescale(DataConverter2d.ToDouble(cOutput));

        dOutput.CropBy((newWidth - image.Width) / 2, (newHeight - image.Height) / 2);

        Bitmap output = DataConverter2d.ToBitmap(dOutput, image.PixelFormat);

        Array2d<Complex> cKernel = FourierTransform.InverseFft(kernel2d);
        cKernel = FourierTransform.RemoveFFTShift(cKernel);
        Array2d<double> dKernel = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(cKernel);
        Array2d<double> dLimitedKernel = Rescale2d.Limit(dKernel);

        Bitmap kernel = DataConverter2d.ToBitmap(dLimitedKernel, image.PixelFormat);

        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        pictureBox2.Image = kernel;
        pictureBox3.Image = output;
    }

    private double Basic(double u, double v, double n, double f0, double rad, double a, double b)
    {
        double ua = u + f0 * Math.Cos(rad);
        double va = v + f0 * Math.Sin(rad);

        double ut = ua * Math.Cos(rad) + va * Math.Sin(rad);
        double vt = (-1) * ua * Math.Sin(rad) + va * Math.Cos(rad);

        double p = ut/a;
        double q = vt/b;

        double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(p*p + q*q);

        return 1.0 / (1.0+ 0.414 * Math.Pow(sqrt, 2*n));
    }

    private double Custom(double u, double v, double n, double f0, double theta, double a)
    {
        double rad1 = (Math.PI / 180) * (90-theta);
        double rad2 = rad1 + Math.PI;
        double b = (a / 5.0) / (2*n);

        double ka = Basic(u, v, n, f0, rad1, a, b);
        double kb = Basic(u, v, n, f0, rad2, a, b);

        return Math.Max(ka, kb);
    }

    private Array2d<Complex> CustomFft(double sizeX, double sizeY, double n, double f0, double theta, double a)
    {
        double halfX = sizeX / 2;
        double halfY = sizeY / 2;

        Array2d<Complex> kernel = new Array2d<Complex>((int)sizeX, (int)sizeY);

        for (double y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            double v = y / sizeY;

            for (double x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
            {
                double u = x / sizeX;

                double kw = Custom(u, v, n, f0, theta, a);

                kernel[(int)x, (int)y] = new Complex(kw, 0);
            }
        }

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

I created a 40-kernel [filter bank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30071474/159072) where each kernel would have same size but different parameters.

This bank of filter is taking around ***55000 milliseconds***  for the kernels to be generated.

How can I reduce this time?

Note: the following line is taking the most time:

```
Array2d<Complex> kernel2d = CustomFft(newWidth, newHeight, n, f0, theta, a);
```

.

*Example source code for creating a kernel bank:*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Bitmap image = DataConverter2d.Read(StandardImage.Scratch1);

        int newWidth = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(image.Width);
        int newHeight = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo(image.Height);

        List<FrequencyDomainKernel> list = new List<FrequencyDomainKernel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {          
            FrequencyDomainKernel k= new FrequencyDomainKernel();
            k.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newWidth, newHeight);
            k.theta = i;
            k.Compute();

            list.Add(k);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: this is not an executable code. This code is just to give an idea regarding my method of generating a kernel.</sup>

Comment: what call is taking the time?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia, the nested for loops.

Comment: which line exactly? is it `k.Compute()`? if so, your best bet is to decrease the width and height of the image... If you replace `DataConverter2d.Read(StandardImage.Scratch1);` with `new Bitmap(64,64)` does the performance improve?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia, `If you replace DataConverter2d.Read(StandardImage.Scratch1); with new Bitmap(64,64) does the performance improve?` --- Yes. Drastically.

Comment: See also `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`. May as well put those extra cores to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop

Comment: You are doing way too many unnecessary calculations in your `Custom()` and `Basic()` functions. For example in your `Custom()`, *rad1, rad2, b* and in `Basic()` *sin(rad) and cos(rad)* can be pre-calculated before the 2 `for loops` in `CustomFft()`! There are many more. Be carefull of `Basic()` cause it is called twice the times than `Custom()`.

Comment: An *FFT* of an image takes around or less than a millisecond. You have too many optimizations to do.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, I could understand *sin* and *cos*, but couldn't understand why *rad1* and *rad2* are redundant. And, what are those `many more`s?

Comment: What is the size of the image and how much time it take only `CustomFft()` to run?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, on an average **1150 milliseconds**.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, **344**x**966** color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, try this:

```
private Array2d<Complex> CustomFft( double sizeX, double sizeY, double n, double f0, double theta,
                                    double a ) {
    double halfX = sizeX / 2;
    double halfY = sizeY / 2;

    //pre-calculated values
    double rad1, rad2, b, f1cos, f1sin, f2cos, f2sin, cosrad1, sinrad1, cosrad2, sinrad2;
    rad1 = ( Math.PI / 180 ) * ( 90 - theta );
    rad2 = rad1 + Math.PI;
    cosrad1 = Math.Cos( rad1 );
    sinrad1 = Math.Sin( rad1 );
    cosrad2 = Math.Cos( rad2 );
    sinrad2 = Math.Sin( rad2 );
    f1cos = f0 * Math.Cos( rad1 );
    f1sin = f0 * Math.Sin( rad1 );
    f2cos = f0 * Math.Cos( rad2 );
    f2sin = f0 * Math.Sin( rad2 );
    b = ( a / 5.0 ) / ( 2 * n );

    Array2d<Complex> kernel = new Array2d<Complex>((int)sizeX, (int)sizeY);

    /*
    for( double y = 0; y < sizeY; y++ ) {
        double v = y / sizeY;

        for( double x = 0; x < sizeX; x++ ) {
            double u = x / sizeX;

            double kw = Custom2( u, v, n, f0, theta, a, rad1, rad2, b, f1cos, f1sin, f2cos, f2sin,
                                 cosrad1, sinrad1 , cosrad2, sinrad2 );

            kernel[ (int)x, (int)y ] = new Complex( kw, 0 );
        }
    }*/

    //reverse the loops
    for( double x = 0; x < sizeX; x++ ) {    
        double u = x / sizeX;

        for( double y = 0; y < sizeY; y++ ) {
            double v = y / sizeY;

            double kw = Custom2( u, v, n, f0, theta, a, rad1, rad2, b, f1cos, f1sin, f2cos, f2sin,
                                  cosrad1, sinrad1, cosrad2, sinrad2 );

            kernel[ (int)x, (int)y ] = new Complex( kw, 0 );
        }
    }

    return kernel;
}

private double Custom2( double u, double v, double n, double f0, double theta, double a,
                        double rad1, double rad2, double b, double f1cos, double f1sin, 
                        double f2cos, double f2sin, double cosrad1, double sinrad1,
                        double cosrad2, double sinrad2 ) {

    double ka = Basic2( u, v, n, f0, rad1, a, b, f1cos, f1sin, cosrad1, sinrad1 );
    double kb = Basic2( u, v, n, f0, rad2, a, b, f2cos, f2sin, cosrad2, sinrad2 );

    return ( ka >= kb ? ka : kb); //Math.Max( ka, kb );
}

private double Basic2( double u, double v, double n, double f0, double rad, double a, double b,
                       double fcos, double fsin, double cosrad, double sinrad ) {
    double ua = u + fcos;
    double va = v + fsin;

    double ut = ua * cosrad + va * sinrad;
    double vt = ( -1 ) * ua * sinrad + va * cosrad;

    double p = ut / a;
    double q = vt / b;

    double sqrt = Math.Sqrt( p * p + q * q );

    return 1.0 / ( 1.0 + 0.414 * Math.Pow( sqrt, 2 * n ) );
}
```

I am going to work on it a little more.

**EDIT 1**

My first observation is that you are using too many classes and in these classes too many methods. The problem with OOP is that sometimes the code is divided into too many classes with very tiny methods which in turn can make the code hard to follow (going through all the classes etc..) and unnecessarily slow for simple things. Let use some numbers:

A simple:

```
Array2d<Complex> cImage = DataConverter2d.ToComplex( dImage );
```

takes arround **65msec**! It just subtitutes the real part of `cImage` with the value of `dImage` and the imaginary is set to `zero`. This trully shouldn't take that much but as I said OOP and classes. Lets do a simple re-configuration and instead of `Array2d<Complex>` use a simple double array:

```
double[] cImagefast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight * 2 ];
```

Thats it. It stores `real-imaginary` parts linearly eg

```
cImagefast[0] -> real part of cImage[0,0]
cImagefast[1] -> imag part of cImage[0,0]
cImagefast[2] -> real part of cImage[0,1]
cImagefast[3] -> imag part of cImage[0,1]
....
```

Lets re-write the code and test it:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Bitmap image = DataConverter2d.ReadGray( "Scratch1.jpg" );
Array2d<double> dImage = DataConverter2d.ToDouble( image );

int newWidth = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo( dImage.Width );
int newHeight = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo( dImage.Height );

dImage.PadTo( newWidth, newHeight ); //~60msec

//Array2d<Complex> cImage = DataConverter2d.ToComplex( dImage ); //~65msec

double[] dImagefast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight ];
double[] cImagefast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight * 2 ];
int count = newWidth * newHeight * 2, pos = 0, pos_ = 0, i;

// fill it with true values before testing
for( int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++ ) {
        dImagefast[ pos ] = dImage[ x, y ];

        pos++;
    }
}

//Start the testing!
sw.Start();

for( pos = 0; pos < count; pos += 2 ){
    cImagefast[ pos ] = dImagefast[ pos_ ];

    pos_++;
}

sw.Stop();

MessageBox.Show( sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() );
```

Time needed **~10msec**. More than 6 times faster!!!!

Lets do another one. Lets test `FFT convolution` which takes **~105msec**

```
// FFT convolution ................................................. ~105msec
Array2d<Complex> fOutput = new Array2d<Complex>( newWidth, newHeight );
for( int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++ ) {
    for( int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++ ) {
        fOutput[ x, y ] = fImage[ x, y ] * kernel2d[ x, y ];
    }
}
```

Re-write it with simple 1 dimension double arrays:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Bitmap image = DataConverter2d.ReadGray( "Scratch1.jpg" );
Array2d<double> dImage = DataConverter2d.ToDouble( image );
int newWidth = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo( dImage.Width );
int newHeight = Tools.ToNextPowerOfTwo( dImage.Height );
double n = 6, f0 = 0.5, theta = 60, a = 0.4;

Array2d<Complex> kernel2d = CustomFft( newWidth, newHeight, n, f0, theta, a );

dImage.PadTo( newWidth, newHeight ); //~60msec
Array2d<Complex> cImage = DataConverter2d.ToComplex( dImage ); //~65msec
Array2d<Complex> fImage = FourierTransform.ForwardFft( cImage );

/*
// FFT convolution ............................................. ~105msec
Array2d<Complex> fOutput = new Array2d<Complex>( newWidth, newHeight );
for( int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++ ) {
    for( int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++ ) {
        fOutput[ x, y ] = fImage[ x, y ] * kernel2d[ x, y ];
    }
}
*/

// Fast FFT convolution ..................................... ~31msec!!!
int pos = 0, count = newWidth * newHeight * 2;
double[] fImagefast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight * 2 ];
double[] kernel2dfast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight * 2 ];

//lets fill the arrays with values
for( int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++ ) {
        kernel2dfast[ pos ] = kernel2d[ x, y ].Real;
        kernel2dfast[ pos + 1 ] = kernel2d[ x, y ].Imaginary;

        pos += 2;
    }
}

pos = 0;
for( int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++ ) {
        fImagefast[ pos ] = fImage[ x, y ].Real;
        fImagefast[ pos + 1 ] = fImage[ x, y ].Imaginary;

        pos += 2;
    }
}

//Test!
sw.Start();
double[] fOutputfast = new double[ newWidth * newHeight * 2 ];

for( pos = 0; pos < count; pos += 2 ) {
    //( left.m_real * right.m_real ) - ( left.m_imaginary * right.m_imaginary );
    fOutputfast[ pos ] = fImagefast[pos] * kernel2dfast[ pos ] - fImagefast[ pos + 1 ] * kernel2dfast[ pos + 1 ];
    //( left.m_imaginary * right.m_real ) + ( left.m_real * right.m_imaginary );
    fOutputfast[ pos + 1 ] = fImagefast[ pos + 1 ] * kernel2dfast[ pos ] + fImagefast[ pos ] * kernel2dfast[ pos + 1 ];
}

sw.Stop();

MessageBox.Show( sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() );
```

The results, **~31msec!!!** more than 3.5 times faster. Imagine how faster the whole code could be if just simple 1 dimension double arrays were used.

These are my first observations. New edits will come later.

**EDIT2**

In this edit we will optimize CustomFFt even more. Some observations. After some manipulation of the equations i come at this:

[image]

From the above`CustomFft` can be written as:

```
private void CustomFftFast( ref float[] kernel, int sizeX, int sizeY, double n, double f0, double theta, double a ) {
    int pos = 0;

    //pre-calculated values
    float rad1, b, cosrad1, sinrad1; //rad2, cosrad2, sinrad2;
    float Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Fo;
    float p1, p2, q1, q2, ka, kb, kw;

    rad1 = ( (float)Math.PI / 180.0f ) * ( 90.0f - (float)theta );
    //rad2 = rad1 + (float)Math.PI;
    cosrad1 = (float)Math.Cos( rad1 );
    sinrad1 = (float)Math.Sin( rad1 );
    //cosrad2 = (float)Math.Cos( rad2 );
    //sinrad2 = (float)Math.Sin( rad2 );
    b = ( (float)a / 5.0f ) / ( 2.0f * (float)n );

    Ax = cosrad1 / ( (float)sizeX * (float)a );
    Bx = sinrad1 / ( (float)sizeX * (float)b );

    Ay = sinrad1 / ( (float)sizeY * (float)a );
    By = cosrad1 / ( (float)sizeY * (float)b );

    Fo = (float)f0 / (float)a;

    kernel = new float[ sizeX * sizeY * 2 ];

    for( int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++ ) {
        for( int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++ ) {
            p1 = Ax * (float)x + Ay * (float)y + Fo;
            q1 = By * (float)y - Bx * (float)x;

            p2 = -Ax * (float)x - Ay * (float)y + Fo;
            q2 = -By * (float)y + Bx * (float)x;

            ka = p1 * p1 + q1 * q1;
            kb = p2 * p2 + q2 * q2;

            //Normal Pow
            ka = 1.0f / ( 1.0f + 0.414f * (float)Math.Pow( ka, n ) );
            kb = 1.0f / ( 1.0f + 0.414f * (float)Math.Pow( kb, n ) );

            /*//Faster Pow, loses in percision though. Ther is another one
              //with better percision but a little slower.
            unsafe
            {
                uint *c = (uint *)&ka;
                float y_ = (float)*c;
                y_ *= 1.0f / (float)( 1 << 23 );
                y_ -= 126.94269504f;

                uint a_ = (uint)( ( 1 << 23 ) * ( y_ * (float)n + 126.94269504f ) );
                float *b_ = (float *)&a_;
                ka = 1.0f / ( 1.0f + 0.414f * ( *b_ ) );

                c = (uint *)&kb;
                y_ = (float)*c;
                y_ *= 1.0f / (float)( 1 << 23 );
                y_ -= 126.94269504f;

                a_ = (uint)( ( 1 << 23 ) * ( y_ * (float)n + 126.94269504f ) );
                b_ = (float *)&a_;
                kb = 1.0f / ( 1.0f + 0.414f * ( *b_ ) );

            }*/

            kw = ka >= kb ? ka : kb;

            kernel[ pos ] = kw;;
            //kernel[ pos + 1 ] = 0.0f;

            pos += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The bottleneck of `CustomFFt` is the `Pow` call. Times:

```
With Math.Pow(),    time = ~110msec
With faster Pow,    time = ~90msec, strange for such a small improvement
Without Pow at all, time = ~10msec! <--
```

Comment: **400 milliseconds** on an average.

Comment: @anonymous You can reverse the 2 for loops. See edit. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @anonymous Anyway. Making FFT faster doesn't make big difference cause 400msec in contrast to 55000msec! is nothing. Can you post a complete working code to test it myself and see if i can improve it?

Comment: `You can reverse the 2 for loops. See edit. Does it make any difference?` --- Nope. Outcome has become unpredictable. It is varying ***from 365 to 650 milliseconds***.

Comment: @anonymous So what part of the code(after the `InitializeComponent();`) you gave me you want to speed up?

Comment: Is improvement on Kernel generation done? If yes, kindly see if you can give me some suggestion regarding the filtering (padding, cropping, and Fourier).

Comment: @anonymous So you want ft, padding and convolution. ft=~325msec, padding = ~60msec, DataConverter2d.ToComplex = ~60msec, FourierTransform.ForwardFft = ~531, FFT convolution = ~105msec. I will try to improve them.

Comment: How about using jagged arrays instead of 1D arrays?  (using 1D arrays is kind of a question of morality to me :D )

Comment: @anonymous I believe jagged arrays are like multidimension ones in performance or a little better. You can test it.